# How to use Typescript with React Router and match

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

## The approach

I'm trying to get my head around Typescript and React Router. I've been struggling...

I currently get the error :

> Property 'params' does not exist on type 'RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>'.ts(2339)"`

```
import React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

const TopicDetail = ({ match }: { match: RouteComponentProps }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
                 ~~~~~~
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopicDetail;
```

### Look ma, no errors!

I *can* get rid of the errors by defining my own `interface`, but I somehow feel it's the wrong way to do it:

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  params: any;
}
const TopicDetail = ({ match }: { match: Props }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopicDetail;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defining an interface for the router params props is the recommended way to go, although you can be a bit more explicit with your interface declaration. When you declare the interface for the props for your component, you can `extend` the `RouteComponentProps` and use your specific params interface as the type variable.

For example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface RouterProps { // type for `match.params`
    topicId: string; // must be type `string` since value comes from the URL
}

interface TopicDetailProps extends RouteComponentProps<RouterProps> {
    // any other props (leave empty if none)
}

const TopicDetail: React.FC<TopicDetailProps> = ({ match }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{ match.params.topicId }</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(TopicDetail);
```

Comment: Ah I guess I was trying to do it in one step. Also, not realizing I needed `withRouter` HOC. Finally, I had to change the `topicId` to type `string` to make it work (not exactly sure why).

Comment: @skube oh yeah the `string` thing, forgot about that... I believe that's because the values come from the url, so they're all strings to start out.